# PHP pack html output into a variable

Tags: php, mysql, count

Is it possible in PHP to grab the output of HTML code into a variable? Basically, I'm searching for a shorthand for this code:

```php
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<div class="headSection">
    <h1><?=$headline?></h1>
    <p><?=$bottomline?></p>
</div>
<?php $contents = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean(); ?>
```

I want the HTML code to be saved in the `$contents` variable.

Comment: did my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use PHP's EOF string

```
$str = <<<EOF
<div class="headSection">
    <h1>$headline</h1>
    <p>$bottomline</p>
</div>
EOF;
    echo $str;
```

Demo http://codepad.org/9OeUiJNJ

Comment: you may use `<<<'EOF'` if you want to emulate the single quote ' string that doesn't parse variables inside, in PHP 5.3, called nowdoc